# Symfony2 CSS files not applied when index route is accessed by /

Tags: php, symfony

i have a index route:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="index")
 * @Template()
 */
```

It renders a twig template, which includes some css files like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'bundles/public/css/bootstrap.min.css' }}" />
```

When i access the site like this:

**app_dev.php**

All is well, but when i redirect, or do

**app_dev.php/**

The css is not applied, and the files included are empty, its quite weird.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using asset prior to the include in the twig template fixed it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/public/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
```